# Hosting a few apps on one large EC2 vs. multiple small EC2s

Tags: amazon-ec2

I can't seem to find an answer about this:  I want to consolidate a few webapps and websites onto one large EC2, rather than spread them out over multiple smaller EC2s.  It seems like this would be more cost efficient.
However, my co-worker says it is best practice to set up multiple EC2s, even though it will cost more.  But he cannot really explain further.

Is this "best practice" still true? Is it simply a relic of older systems when companies would have large servers running on-site?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each have their pros and cons that you need to weigh. One server means all eggs in one basket. Separate servers mean you can tailor to security of each instance to the things just on that instance. Separate means you can do maintenance on one without interrupting the others.

Answer (score 1):

If an application is able to be run across multiple Amazon EC2 instances (that is, if the application can "**Horizontally Scale**"), it is recommended to do so because it makes the application more resilient to problems, eg:

- **If one instance fails**, the others can take the load
- **If an Availability Zone fails**, instances in the other Availability Zone(s) can take the load
- Maintenance can be performed on an instance with less impact to users
- **Auto Scaling** can be used to add/remove capacity based upon demand

Please note that this is talking about a single application running across multiple instances. In your case, you have multiple applications. They could also be spread across multiple instances too. Each instance could serve multiple applications.

Of course, if your applications are designed to only operate on one server, then it would not be possible to horizontally scale the applications. In that case, one server is sufficient for all your applications but make sure you have a recovery process in place in case of failure.

**Bottom line:** You can have as many apps as you want on one server, but it's good practice to horizontally scale each application across multiple servers (if the app can do so).